# Commutator of covariant derivatives

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, momentum, commutator

I just started studying QFT and I don't understand the last lecture.
In the lecture script a shortcut is defined as:
$$P^j = \frac{1}{i}\partial_j - qA^j.$$
With this:
$$[P^j,P^k] = -\frac{q}{i}(\partial_j A^k - \partial_k A^j).$$
I have a hard time understanding this commutator, since I would get:
$$[P^j,P^k] = -\frac{q}{i}(\partial_j A^k - A^k\partial_j - \partial_k A^j + A^j\partial_k).$$

What do I not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the commutator acting on a function $f$. Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
[ P_i , P_j ] f &= [ - i \partial_i - q A_i , - i \partial_j - q A_j ]f \\
&= ( i \partial_i + q A_i )(  i \partial_j + q A_j ) f  -(  i \partial_j + q A_j )  ( i \partial_i + q A_i ) f  \\
&= -  \partial_i \partial_j   + i q A_i \partial_j \, f + i q \partial_i ( A_j f ) + q^2 A_i A_j \, f\,\, -\,\, i\, \leftrightarrow \,j \\
&= i q ( \partial_i A_j - \partial_j A_i ) f 
\end{split}
\end{equation}